# Help understanding the proof of a theorem on entanglement monotones

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I currently read the paper of Guifre Vidal about Entanglement Monotones ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9807077)). On page 5 he states the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1** The maximal probability of success $P(\rho \rightarrow \rho*)$ in the converion of $\rho \rightarrow \rho*$ that the parties can
>   achieve by means of a strategy involving only LQCC [local quantum
>   operations assisted with classical communication] is
>   given by
>   $$P(\rho \rightarrow \rho*)=\min \frac{\mu(\rho)}{\mu(\rho*)}$$
>   where the minimization is performed over the hole set of all Entanglement Monotones $\mu$.

The proof of this theorem is very short and it seems obvious from Vidal's point of view, but I don't understand it. Can anyone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the probability of success for any strategy is upper bounded by $\mu(\rho)/\mu(\rho^*)$ as seen in eq (14), this will in particular also hold for the strategy that achieve the maximal probability of success $P[\rho\rightarrow\rho^*]$. Note that eq. (14) holds for any entanglement monotone $\mu$ so the entanglement monotone that minimise $\mu(\rho)/\mu(\rho^*)$ is therefore also an upper bound. This means we have the following inequality,
$$P[\rho\rightarrow\rho^*]\leq\min_{\mu}\frac{\mu(\rho)}{\mu(\rho^*)}.\tag{I}$$
We now need to show that this is actually an equality. One way to see this is to first note that
$$\min_{\mu}\frac{\mu(\rho)}{\mu(\rho^*)}\leq\frac{\mu'(\rho)}{\mu'(\rho^*)}\tag{II}$$
for any fixed entanglement monotone $\mu'$. Then we can use the fact that $P[\rho\rightarrow\rho^*]$ defines an entanglement monotone given by
$$\mu_{\rho^*}(\rho)=P[\rho\rightarrow\rho^*].\tag{III}$$
Putting this into equation (II) we have that
$$\min_{\mu}\frac{\mu(\rho)}{\mu(\rho^*)}\leq\frac{\mu_{\rho^*}(\rho)}{\mu_{\rho^*}(\rho^*)}=\frac{P[\rho\rightarrow\rho^*]}{P[\rho^*\rightarrow\rho^*]}=P[\rho\rightarrow\rho^*]\tag{IV}$$
where we used that $P[\rho^*\rightarrow\rho^*]=1$. Finally putting this into equation (I) we have that
$$\min_{\mu}\frac{\mu(\rho)}{\mu(\rho^*)}\leq P[\rho\rightarrow\rho^*]\leq \min_{\mu}\frac{\mu(\rho)}{\mu(\rho^*)}\tag{V}$$
which implies that
$$P[\rho\rightarrow\rho^*]=\min_{\mu}\frac{\mu(\rho)}{\mu(\rho^*)}\tag{VI}$$